# Clean and match data entries in two tables

Tags: python, excel, join, match, google-colaboratory

Data Structure:
Tables A and B contain numerous entries.
Both tables have the same columns: country, state, and city. Entries in Table A are represented as (xa,ya,za) and in Table B as (xb,yb,zb).
Table Characteristics:
Table A is an excel file:
Entries might be unclean but they are in English.
Cities are anglicized, e.g., "Milan" instead of "Milano".
Table B:
Entries might be unclean and in non-English names.

Preparation:
Standardize the formats of Tables A and B for later matching.
Two city lists are available:
city1000.txt is a text file: Contains cities in their original names.
alternatenames.txt is a txt file: Contains potential English translations of cities.
Create an 'anglicised list' from these two lists. The goal is to use the English version of a city name when available. This list should be as exhaustive as city1000.txt.

Process:
Clean the data in Table B using the anglicised list of cities.
Ensure the global list of cities is standardized for consistent matching.
For cities in Table B that don't match any in the global list:
Find the nearest match and create Table F. This table pairs the original entry from B with its closest match.
Highlight cities in F where no match is found.
Compare the cleaned entries of B with A:
Matched entries go into Table C.
Unmatched entries go into Table D.

I tried this but it's not giving me the wanted results, can you help me out?

#### Loading Data from Excel Files

```py
import pandas as pd
 
# Load data from Excel
table_A = pd.read_excel('path_to_table_A.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
table_B = pd.read_excel('path_to_table_B.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

#### Preparing the Anglicized Names Dataset

```py
# Load Geonames data
column_names_alternate = ["alternateNameId", "geonameid", "isolanguage", "alternate_name", "isPreferredName", "isShortName", "isColloquial", "isHistoric", "from", "to"]
alternate_names_df = pd.read_csv('path_to_alternateNames.txt', sep='\t', header=None, names=column_names_alternate, low_memory=False, dtype=str)
 
column_names_cities = ["geonameid", "name", "asciiname", "alternatenames", "latitude", "longitude", "feature class", "feature code", "country code", "cc2", "admin1 code", "admin2 code", "admin3 code", "admin4 code", "population", "elevation", "dem", "timezone", "modification date"]
cities_df = pd.read_csv('path_to_cities1000.txt', sep='\t', header=None, names=column_names_cities, low_memory=False, dtype=str)
 
# Filter for English names
english_names_df = alternate_names_df[alternate_names_df['isolanguage'] == 'en']
 
# Merge with main Geonames dataset to get anglicized names
merged_df = pd.merge(english_names_df, cities_df, on='geonameid', how='inner')
final_df = merged_df[['alternate_name', 'name', 'country code']]
final_df.columns = ['Anglicized Name', 'Original Name', 'Country Code']
```

#### Data Cleaning

```py
def clean_data(df):
    return df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).lower().strip())
 
table_B_clean = clean_data(table_B)
```

#### Anglicizing City Names in Table B

Use the `final_df` to anglicize city names in Table B:

```py
def anglicize_city(city):
    anglicized_name = final_df[final_df['Original Name'].str.lower() == city]['Anglicized Name'].values
    return anglicized_name[0] if anglicized_name.size > 0 else city
 
table_B_clean['City'] = table_B_clean['City'].apply(anglicize_city)
```

#### Generating Table F

Find the closest matching city for each city in `table_B_clean`:

```py
import difflib
 
def find_closest_city(city, choices):
    closest_match = difflib.get_close_matches(city, choices, n=1)
    return closest_match[0] if closest_match else city
 
table_B_clean['closest_city'] = table_B_clean['City'].apply(lambda x: find_closest_city(x, final_df['Anglicized Name'].tolist()))
table_F = table_B.copy()
table_F['closest_city'] = table_B_clean['closest_city']
table_F['match_found'] = table_F['City'] == table_F['closest_city']
```

#### Generate Tables C and D

Compare the cleaned entries of Table B with Table A:

```py
merged_table = pd.merge(table_A, table_B_clean, on=['Country', 'State', 'City'], how='outer', indicator=True)
table_C = merged_table[merged_table['_merge'] == 'both'].drop(columns=['_merge'])
table_D = merged_table[merged_table['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop(columns=['_merge'])
```

#### Save Results to Excel

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('table_C.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    table_C.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Table C')
 
with pd.ExcelWriter('table_D.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    table_D.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Table D')
 
with pd.ExcelWriter('table_F.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    table_F.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Table F')
 
with pd.ExcelWriter('anglicized_cities.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    final_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name
```

Comment: You are more likely to receive assistance if you include a data set **as text** which can be copy/pasted that is can be used to demonstrate your problem; and also show examples of your actual vs expected results. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)